# Is it possible to implement a timer in a Apache Storm bolt?

Tags: java, timer, missing-data, apache-storm, stream-processing

A Bolt's code is triggered when data arrives (an input tuple). How can we program code inside a Bolt to run even in the case of missing input data? I mean, if no tuple arrives how can we force an action to be accomplished? Are timers allowed?

Answer (score 0):

The main routine of a bolt is inside the `execute`-Function as documented [here](https://storm.apache.org/releases/current/javadocs/org/apache/storm/task/IBolt.html#execute-org.apache.storm.tuple.Tuple-). To the best of my knowledge, this automatically called by the underlying `supervisor`, when a new tuple arrives and this is something you cannot easily change without forking Storm. However, if you want to have an ongoing routine in a bolt, than you could maybe start a parallel thread in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely use timers to trigger logic to run as part of a bolt, and to emit using the bolt's `OutputCollector`. I did this in production in the past. You'll probably want to use Storm's `IRichBolt` interface to allow utilizing the bolt's `OutputCollector` across different threads.

Another option you have handy in Storm is tick tuples. Those are tuples you configure Storm to send your bolt at a given interval. These are often much more useful than using timers because they don't require extra threads, and as a result also behave much nicer when your stream is back-pressured.